# What happens to I/O pins in Low Power Mode on MSP430

Tags: msp430

I'm reading the datasheet for the [MSP430G2553](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2553.pdf) about the low power modes that the microcontroller has but it doesn't talk about what happens to the IO Ports when it enters low power modes. It only talks about the what happens to the clocks like so:

> • Active mode (AM)
>   – All clocks are active
>
> • Low-power mode 0 (LPM0)
>   – CPU is disabled
>   – ACLK and SMCLK remain active, MCLK is disabled
>
> • Low-power mode 1 (LPM1)
>   – CPU is disabled
>   – ACLK and SMCLK remain active, MCLK is disabled
>   – DCO's dc generator is disabled if DCO not used in active mode
>
> • Low-power mode 2 (LPM2)
>   – CPU is disabled
>   – MCLK and SMCLK are disabled
>   – DCO's dc generator remains enabled
>   – ACLK remains active
>
> • Low-power mode 3 (LPM3)
>   – CPU is disabled
>   – MCLK and SMCLK are disabled
>   – DCO's dc generator is disabled
>   – ACLK remains active
>
> • Low-power mode 4 (LPM4)
>   - CPU is disabled
>   - ACLK is disabled
>   - MCLK and SMCLK are disabled DCO's dc generator is disabled Crystal oscillator is stopped

So what happens to the IO ports? Is it a given that they remain in the state before it enters the low power mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A lot isn't explained in the chip's own datasheet. With 450 processor models, this makes perfect sense : the datasheet describes the chip-specific stuff; common information is refactored out into a user manual covering the entire family of devices.

The user manual for that device family is

> [MSP430x2xx Family User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf)
>
> Literature Number: SLAU144J

Operating modes, ch 2.3, p.38 says:

> When setting any of the mode-control bits, the selected operating mode takes effect immediately (see
>   Figure 2-9). Peripherals operating with any disabled clock are disabled until the clock becomes active. The
>   peripherals may also be disabled with their individual control register settings. All I/O port pins and
>   RAM/registers are unchanged. Wake up is possible through all enabled interrupts.

So, the I/O pins retain their current function and (for output pins) values.

In other words if you're trying to save power, any power they are supplying to LEDs etc is your problem (turn them off, along with peripherals you don't need, before sleeping).

Comment: Thats such a small paragraph on that page, I can't believe i missed it. As I searched for LPM in the Family User Guide.

Comment: well it's fresh in the  mind; I've just been getting the Ada compiler to enter/leave low power modes and handle interrupts today!

Comment: @BrianDrummond: it's good practice to add a link to any document you refer to. I added a link to your answer.

Comment: sorry, revision above is no longer available.   now it is rev j:   http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf